# How to use imports and implicits in Play Framework's routes file?

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, implicit

What's the scope for `routes` file to find `implicit`s like `PathBindable` or `QueryStringBindable`?

For custom types, it's trivial to simply define them in companion object like the following:

```
case class Foo(data: String)
object Foo {
  implicit val pathBinder: PathBindable[Foo] = ???
}
```

However, for existing types, it's unclear where to declare implicit to be found by `routes` file since we cannot do any custom `import` here.

So, **What's the scope of implicits for routes file?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but it seems relevant...

You can include custom imports in the `routes` file by adding to the `routesImport` key in your `build.sbt`

For example:

```
import play.PlayImport.PlayKeys._

routesImport += "my.custom.package.Foo._"
```

That snippet is borrowed from a blog post I wrote a while ago entitled [Using Play-Framework's PathBindable](http://cjwebb.github.io/blog/2015/06/23/play-framework-path-binders/)

Comment: I knew there would be something like this! Thank you and happy new year :]

Comment: for me to get the `routesImport` key i had to import `play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport`

Comment: The blog post that the author mentioned has been moved to here: https://cjwebb.com/play-framework-path-binders/

Answer (score 8):

we had a queryStringBindable that we needed to use and had a similar situation, we found this question which gave us a clue but the answer from colinjwebb is out of date.

Here's our example which goes from a string to an Option[LoginContext].

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, AnyContent, QueryStringBindable, Request}
...

object BindableLoginContext {

  implicit def queryStringBindable(implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]) = new QueryStringBindable[LoginContext] {
    override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, LoginContext]] =
      for {
        loginContextString <- stringBinder.bind(key, params)
      } yield {
        loginContextString match {
          case Right(value) if value.toLowerCase == "web" => Right(LoginContexts.Web)
          case Right(value) if value.toLowerCase == "api" => Right(LoginContexts.Api)
          case _ => Left(s"Unable to bind a loginContext from $key")
        }
      }

    override def unbind(key: String, loginContext: LoginContext): String = stringBinder.unbind(key, loginContext.toString)
  }
}
```

To use it we needed to use the following import:

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys
```

and then add the object to the Project like this

```
lazy val microservice = Project(appName, file("."))
  .settings(
    RoutesKeys.routesImport += "controllers.BindableLoginContext._"
  )
```